# Background mail sending service using Microsoft account

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth, daemon

We are developing a centralized email notifications service (let's call it `EmailService`) in **.NET Core 3.1**. Its purpose is to expose a REST API endpoint (ex. `POST /SendMail`) which will be available to all other company applications. When some application calls `/SendMail`, it passes fields such as `to`, `cc`, `subject` and `htmlBody` in JSON format. `EmailService` then sends the email from **Microsoft account** to the given emails with specified content. Think of it like `no-reply@company.com` notification.

Diagram:

[image]

From this description it is quite obvious that `EmailService` is some kind of background-running deamon process without user interaction. When its REST API endpoint `/SendMail` is called, it must authenticate against Microsoft server and send an email to the customer.

We are using [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) for sending email messages and **SMTP** client/protocol like this:

```cs
using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
    client.Connect ("smtp.friends.com", 587, false);

    client.Authenticate ("no-reply@company.com", "access_token");

    client.Send (message);
    client.Disconnect (true);
}
```

I have the following questions:

1. How should I configure "App registration" inside Azure portal for our use case (daemon background process)?
2. How should I handle the tokens inside .NET Core application? I assume that there should be some kind of never-expiring(?) `refresh_token` which can be used to retrieve new `access_token` when it expires?
3. We should use `https://graph.microsoft.com/SMTP.Send` scope, right?
4. Since `EmailService` will be a long-running process it should follow the principle: "configure once, work automatically from then on".